# Where did the data enter in this optimization problem?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I wonder, how the following code works:

```
import scipy.optimize as sco

n_assets = 7

def min_func_sharpe(weights):                           # Function to be minimized. Minimize Negative Sharpe Ratio.
    return - port_ret(weights) / port_vol(weights)

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1}) 
bnds = tuple((0, 1) for x in range(n_assets))          

eweights = np.array(n_assets * [1. / n_assets,])        # Start optimization with equal weights vector.


opts = sco.minimize(min_func_sharpe, eweights, method='SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)
```

opts now contains the optimized weights for the data (which was imported in Jupyter Notebook). But where exactly did the data enter in this optimization process?

Comment: If your goal is just to minimize a function, then you don't need data... ie `scipy.optimize.minimize` doesn't use data to perform the minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `scipy.optimize.minimize` example you showed is provided 5 arguments.

1. `min_func_sharpe`: This is the function that you want scipy to minimize the return value.
2. `eweights`: This is what you are providing to scipy as the starting point for the optimization. For the best chance of success, this should be close to the optimal value.
3. `method='SLSQP'`: This is telling scipy which minimization method it should use to solve the problem. In this case, you're telling it to use the [Sequential Least Squares Programming](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-slsqp.html#optimize-minimize-slsqp) method.
4. `bounds=bnds`: Here you are providing the upper and lower bounds the solution variables can take. In this case, you told it that all the values must be between 0 and 1, inclusive.
5. `constraints=cons`: This last argument tells scipy that you also want to constrain the variables using a function. In this case, you gave an equality constraint that says that all the variables should sum up to 1.

As you can see, the only "data" provided to the `scipy.optimize.minimize` function is a starting guess for the variables. Behind the scenes, scipy will evaluate your objective function, `min_func_sharpe`, iterate the solution variables, and check that it is satisfying the bounds and constraints you gave. The results are saved into `opts`, which you can access. In the end, scipy will either successfully find an optimum and have a solution vector that it generated (accessed using `opts.x`), or it will fail (if it failed, you will have `opts.success == False`).